# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type AttributeValidatorFactory, key ""

Tags: asp.net, validation, enterprise-library

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and Enterprise Library Validation 5.0.505.0 in my class library. But I'm facing error like

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type AttributeValidatorFactory, key ""

I face error on the following line.

```
Validation.ValidateFromAttributes(obj);
```

where obj is the custom object.
I don't how to solve this one. Please, help !!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just add the Microsoft EnterpriseLibrary reference to my Website. In my case the DLL Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation resides in the following path

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0\Bin\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.dll

To find out the path you should follow the step.

> Right Click on the DLL > Click on Properties > Here there is property naming
>   **Path**

And a very small trick.

> *Right Click on the DLL > Click on Properties > Make **Copy Local** to **True** (By default the property is **False**)*

Now, I Clean my solution and Build it and re-run the solution.
The application is running properly without any error. BINGO !!!!